# Sub select or group by

Tags: mysql

Hello have `users` table, related many-to-many with another table.

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47a5a/4)

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50)
);
;
CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE user_items (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id int NOT NULL,
    item_id int NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(id)
)
```

What is the best way to display the user information + count(of the related items) ?
I tried 2 queries .. but they both have some disadvantages:

```
SELECT u.*,
 (SELECT count(id) FROM user_items WHERE user_id = u.id) as items_count
FROM users u;


SELECT u.*,
 COUNT(ui.id) as items_count
FROM users u
JOIN user_items ui ON ui.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name;
```

The sub select query .. will become heavy when this tables become big ..(and they will).

The grouping query .. force me to put all user fields in the GROUP BY ... to have a normal result witch becomes inconvenient for real data .. and for structure updates.

What is the best practice in this scenario ?
Also what is the optimal scenario for speed optimization if the table become large ?

Comment: What is the result you would like ? (Just to be sure)

Comment: Depends on what result you want, if you only want statistics i should only use the table user_items, else i would join user + user_items and count user_items. You could consider making a view for the query this way mysql can index/cache data better.

Comment: all user column and a "item_count" with the count of items he "has".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in MySQL you don't **have** to either aggregate or group by an item to include it in a grouped result set:

```
SELECT u.*,
       COUNT(*) as items_count
FROM users u
JOIN user_items ui ON ui.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Alternatively, you could group inside an inline view in the from clause:

```
SELECT u.*,
       ui.items_count
FROM users u
JOIN (select user_id, COUNT(*) as items_count 
      from user_items 
      group by user_id) ui 
  ON ui.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47a5a/8).

Comment: what is the difference of normal join and inline join like this ?

Comment: @d.raev: What do you mean, "an inline join like this"? Are you referring to the second query?

Comment: When you JOIN (or select from) a subquery MySQL runs the subquery first and then the rest of the query using the temporary result set as a table.

Comment: So it gets executed once .. and probably fetching only indexed columns .. sounds interesting :)